# Changing Word header font and size

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have a C# program that replaces the header in a Word document with what is in the clipboard.  It works fine:  `selection.Paste();`  However, changing the font size and name does not work.  Below is a snippet of the code.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
selection.Font.Size = 14;
selection.Font.Name = "Arial";
selection.Paste();
```